# Unexpected nginx behavior

Tags: nginx

I have the following block in my nginx config:

```
location ~ /$ {
    index index.html index.cgi index.pl index.php index.xhtml index.htm index.shtml;
}

location /cat {
    try_files /index.php?url=$uri =404;
}
```

What I expect this to do: Any request sent to `http://www.example.com/cat<whatever>` will be sent to index.php with the GET variable url set to the request uri. What happens instead based on the rewrite log is that the `location /cat` block is never hit at all. Here is a relevant excerpt from the rewrite log when I request `http://www.example.com/cart/testing/`:

```
2017/03/21 00:32:49 [error] 25711#0: *20566477 "/var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/cat/testing/index.html" is not found (2: No such file or directory), client: <ip redacted>, server: example.com, request: "GET /cat/testing/ HTTP/1.1", host: "www.example.com"
```

There are no other entries related to the request.

It was my understanding that nginx processes any prefix location blocks (i.e. `location /cat`) BEFORE any location blocks involving regex (i.e. `location ~ /$`). So I'm stumped by this behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your *understanding* is incorrect. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details.

Also, your `try_files` directive is incorrect. Either `/index.php?url=$uri` or `=404` should be the last element in the statement. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) for details.

You probably want:

```
index index.html index.cgi index.pl index.php index.xhtml index.htm index.shtml;

location /cat {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?url=$uri;
}
```

Not sure of the purpose of the other location block, as the `index` directive is already going to process any URI with a trailing `/`. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_index_module.html#index) for details.